# Can I override properties of a parameter definition object when referencing it?

Tags: swagger

I have some parameter defined in the root parameters

```
parameters:
   fooParam:
      name: foo
      in: query
      description: Foo foo foo.
      required: false
      type: number
      format: int32
```

Now I reference it in a path

```
/pathOne:
   get:
      parameters:
         - $ref: "#/parameters/fooParam"
```

Let say I want to use that parameter in another path or method, but I want it to be required (required: true)

```
/pathTwo:
   get:
      parameters:
         - ?????????????????
```

Is there a way to reference the same parameter and override one or more of its properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there isn't. This is a limitation of JSON References rather than a limitation of Swagger.